# "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add new users to my user database but I am getting this error:

> A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type at `cmd.Connection = new connection;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace _Users
{
    public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnRegistration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|userDb.accdb";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users (firstname, surname, Username, Email, Password, Contact) VALUES (@firstname, @surname, @Username, @Email, @Password, @Contact)");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = new connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtbFN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtbSN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtbUsrN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtbEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtbPassW.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtbCnt.Text);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line

```
cmd.Connection = new connection;
```

and replace it with

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

The `new` keyword says you want to create a new instance of a class.

You also have to replace `connection.Open();` with `conn.Open();` (thanks @p.s.w.g. for the comment)

Comment: OP will also need to fix the line `connection.Open();`

Comment: thanks when i run it, its giving me an error  OleDbException was unhandled by user code Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. @  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Seems to be an error in the SQL statement but I can't see any. Have you tried this query directly on your database (for example with SQL Server Management Studio or whatever application you use)?

Comment: I think "password" is a reserved keyword in SQL

Comment: just added square brackets around password and that works Thanks for your help Eric

Answer (score 0):

Just before your last block, you defined a connection named `conn`. 
Now that you want to store it in a `Connection` object, you simply have to write :

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

And, as you want to open the connection stored in `cmd`, then you call the `Open` methods on the `cmd.Connection` using:

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

Concerning your exception, a `new` key word must always be followed by a class constructor. Those constructors looks like `MyClass.MyConstructor(someParameters)`.

Answer (score 0):

Note the unhighlighted text in your code.

```
cmd.Connection = new connection;
```

This means, that there is no class named: **connection**. Replace it with

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

You are passing on a parameter in the method. This would be used here. Then you'll open the link using

```
conn.Open();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users (firstname, surname, Username, Email, Password, Contact) VALUES (@firstname, @surname, @Username, @Email, @Password, @Contact)");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = conn ;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtbFN.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtbSN.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtbUsrN.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtbEmail.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtbPassW.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtbCnt.Text);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```